# Как перевести на русский Voyager для Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Хочу создать сайт для клиента с помощью Laravel, в качестве админки планирую использовать Voyager. Еще не ставил, пока только читаю о нем...

Можно ли перевести Voyager на русский? Там есть файл локализации или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Судя по сорсам нельзя. Если только ручками идти по всем файлам.

Comment: Понял, жаль :( Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в новом релизе будет добавлена возможность локализации. И кстати, перевод интерфейса на русский уже залит в мастер ветку :)

Answer (score 1):

В версии 1.3 зайти в "Users" и отредактировать профиль админа где надо указать локаль "ru"